# Network Manager ipv6.method=disabled from which version?

Tags: puppet, ipv6, networkmanager

Does anyone know, from which version is in Network Manager available option disabled? I am writing puppet module and to write it propperly I have to specify in which version to use ignore and where to use disabled for ipv6.method property inside keyfile.

I found out that EL7 uses ignore and EL8 uses disabled, but I want to write it for many distros, so I need to specify exact version of NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. To use ipv6.method=disable, the version of NM must be 1.20 and greater.